# How to force index on a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have indexed some entries containing a GEOJson point object :

exemple :

```
  {
      "_id": "48LEDd5imvEpFnCQx",
      "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-2.7577078342437744, 47.65381454210301]
      },
      "geoip": false,
      "trackerId": "RG-DEMO-1",
      "date": "2015-07-25T21:12:07.286Z"
  }
```

The mapping:

```
        {
        'trace': {
            'properties': {
                'loc': {
                    'type': 'nested',
                    'properties': {
                        'type': {
                            'type': 'string'
                        },
                        'coordinates':{
                            'type': 'geo_point',
                            'geohash':true,
                            'geohash_prefix':true,
                            'lat_lon':true,
                            'fielddata' : {
                                'format' : 'compressed',
                                'precision' : '1cm'
                            }
                        }
                    }
        ...
```

The geohash is generated but Kibana says that loc.coordinates is not indexed and I can't use the visualisation map `Unindexed fields can not be searched`

What is the trick to force index on this type of field?

Comment: it works for me ? check with   *curl -XPOST <index_name>/_search" -d'
{
    "sort": [
       {
          "loc.coordinates.geohash" : {"order" : "desc"}
       }
    ]
 }'* you should be able to view geohash values

Comment: Exact! Your query shiws me the geohash. But why I have not access through Kibana? (I am on my phone by now. I will rewrite the question asap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) `nested`type sub object are not indexed:

So there are two workarounds:

- For keeping `loc` as a nested object, add a `include_in_parent` wildcard to `true`
- Or, turn the `loc` type to `Object`.